# woocommerce: join post and product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a e-commerce website and I would like to know if it's possible to have the same category for posts and woocommerce products ? I would like to get both articles and products from specific category. I've tried this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/relating-a-post-to-a-product-category which make products categories appears in posts but I don't know how to display them in posts loop.

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <header>    
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_tags('<ul class="entry-tags"><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
    the_category( ' ' ); ?>
  </header>

<div>
   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
    ?>
</div>

</article>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since products are posts, you can make regular posts and products share same category.

Comment: Explain more what you are trying to accomplish and what have you tried so far to be able to better help you.

Comment: the posts and products category seems separate each other

Comment: I fact, I would like to add a sidebar with 'general' categories. When you click on 'French' category for example, I would like to get posts and products with this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout https://wordpress.org/support/topic/relating-a-post-to-a-product-category

The main idea is to modify the taxonomy to allow categories used for products and posts, or better create new taxonomy to prevent polluting the original taxonomy.

Comment: I've checked this solution before which doesn't works.

Comment: Let's start with what exactly did you do and why didn't it work? did you get errors? or it just didn't accomplish what you want?

Comment: I found an alternative solution by using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/ It's allows to search everything by category.